# Async Promises inside for loop inside for loop

Tags: node.js

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [3, 4, 5];


for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    console.log('value of i is ', i);
    for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
        console.log('value of j is ', j);
        here some blocking code like setTimeout or any database call
    }
}
```

I want this output

```
value of i is ',0
value of j is ',0
value of j is ',1
value of j is ',2
value of i is ',1
value of j is ',0
value of j is ',1
value of j is ',2
```

Comment: what does it currently give you? also good idea to have your code use comments when for //here some blocking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use async and await to do that. [Async/Await](https://javascript.info/async-await) is working with promises:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [3, 4, 5];

async function asyncStuff(a, b) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        console.log('value of i is ', i);
        for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
            console.log('value of j is ', j);
            // Waits until the promise has resolved and continues the for-loop
            await someDatabaseCall();
        }
    }
}
// Call your function
asyncStuff(a, b);
```

Be aware that async/await does not block the execution of the `Array.forEach`.